# MS VC++ 2008 Linker error std::out_of_range

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I've been trying to compile a program that makes use of a library I built. The library compiles successfully, but I cannot compile a program using it. The error I get is listed below. I feel there is some silly little thing I’ve missed. The statement “std::out_of_range” is used only once and is in the form “throw std::out_of_range(“Message”);” and the stdexcept header file has been included. Any help would be warmly welcomed. Thanks.

> fatal error LNK1237: during code generation, compiler introduced
>   reference to symbol public: __thiscall
>   std::out_of_range::out_of_range(class std::out_of_range const &)" …
>   compiled with /GL

Comment: Can you post some code? Especially the part where you include stdexcept.h

Comment: I found the reference, still cannot understand the point http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/at5twzkt(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: I found the same link. Have you tried compiling without /GL? According to your output you are compiling with it, and the link Lol4t0 and I found suggests not compiling with it to make the linker error go away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing the /GL option when you go to compile as suggested here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/at5twzkt.aspx

Leave a comment if that does not fix it, and I can try to look for a further solution.

Answer (score 0):

Remove optimization in linker and C++ options for your project. Do not compile with /GL option

Comment: What? Care to explain how doing *any* of those things will help with this error?

Comment: He probably came across the same MSDN page I and another user did. The page itself recommends not compiling with the /GL option as a way to get rid of this linker error.

Comment: Sorry your answer was not there when I started posting mine. My understanding is that std::out_of_range is optimized out of symbols table since it is declared but not referenced in the same compilation unit. Then linker discovers that it does need the symbol when working on the other unit. This points to single pass linker. By removing optimization you are making sure no symbols are thrown out. You can also force symbol inclusion by using /INCLUDE as described in an article.